# AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException: Cognito Invalid AttributeDataType

Tags: aws-cdk

I like to create a cognito user pool via AWS-CDK version 0.24.1 based on Java. During `cdk deploy` i get the error InvalidParameterException.

**Service:** AWSCognitoIdentityProvider;
**Status Code:** 400;
**Error Code:** InvalidParameterException: Cognito Invalid AttributeDataType input, consider using the provided AttributeDataType enum

```
    CfnUserPool userPool = new CfnUserPool(this, "cognito",
    CfnUserPoolProps.builder()
        .withAdminCreateUserConfig(
            AdminCreateUserConfigProperty.builder()
                .withAllowAdminCreateUserOnly(false)
                .build())
        .withPolicies(
            PoliciesProperty.builder()
                .withPasswordPolicy(
                    PasswordPolicyProperty.builder()
                        .withMinimumLength(6)
                        .withRequireLowercase(false)
                        .withRequireNumbers(false)
                        .withRequireSymbols(false)
                        .withRequireUppercase(false)
                        .build()
                )
                .build()
        )
        .withAutoVerifiedAttributes(Arrays.asList("email"))
        .withSchema(Arrays.asList("email"))
    .build());
```

Maybe the simple string list `.withAutoVerifiedAttributes(Arrays.asList("email"))` or     `.withSchema(Arrays.asList("email"))` is wrong. But unfortunately there is only list of object declared in method signature and no concret typ: `public CfnUserPoolProps.Builder withAutoVerifiedAttributes(@Nullable List value)`.

Is there an example snippte to create a similar userpool using aws-cdk based on Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usage of `CfnUserPool.SchemaAttributeProperty.builder()` resolved the problem. I think `SchemaAttributeProperty` is the expected data type of the method `withSchema(@Nullable List< Object > value)`

```
CfnUserPool userPool = new CfnUserPool(this, "cognito",
    CfnUserPoolProps.builder()
        .withAdminCreateUserConfig(
            AdminCreateUserConfigProperty.builder()
                .withAllowAdminCreateUserOnly(false)
                .build())
        .withPolicies(
            PoliciesProperty.builder()
                .withPasswordPolicy(
                    PasswordPolicyProperty.builder()
                        .withMinimumLength(6)
                        .withRequireLowercase(false)
                        .withRequireNumbers(false)
                        .withRequireSymbols(false)
                        .withRequireUppercase(false)
                        .build()
                )
                .build()
        )
       .withAutoVerifiedAttributes(Arrays.asList("email"))
       .withSchema(Arrays.asList(
           CfnUserPool.SchemaAttributeProperty.builder()
               .withAttributeDataType("String")
               .withName("email")
               .withRequired(true)
           .build()))
    .build());
```